# Retrieving Shibboleth attributes from AJP connector request

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7, shibboleth, ajp

I have encountered a weird problem when working with Shibboleth authentication running on Apache and when Tomcat7 running on the back end, Apache sends everything through mod_proxy_ajp. And so it does with parameters from Shibboleth.

In the [documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall) it is explicitly stated that AJP sends only attributes with prefix `attributePrefix="AJP_"` and that a developer should not take shortcuts and enable sending auth attributes through HTTP headers: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPSpoofChecking

I try to retrieve attributes using

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                         .getExternalContext().getRequest();

Enumeration<String> e = req.getAttributeNames();
```

But no matter what I try, no Shibboleth attributes ever show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After two hours of trying to find out what I was doing wrong. I tried to retrieve attribute by name using.

```
req.getAttribute("uid");
```

And for some reason that works. Even though the `"uid"` isn't listed in getAttributeNames();

It smells like a bug, or mistimed communication somewhere between AJP and Spring or JSF...

Comment: Actually using req.getAttribute("uid") is documented at https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeAccess#NativeSPAttributeAccess-Tool-SpecificExamples for Java. - 

Also this is interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974233/shibboleth-sp-reading-assertion-attributes-from-java