# Shibboleth SP - Reading assertion attributes from Java

Tags: java, apache, single-sign-on, shibboleth, ajp

I understand that configured attributes will be stored as environment variables by default and will be accessible like

```
request.getAttribute("Shib-Identity-Provider")
```

I tried that and after some googling I understood that to access them in Java through AJP.

I need to prefix this

```
<ApplicationDefaults id="default" policyId="default"
    entityID="https://idp.example.org"
    REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
    signing="false" encryption="false" attributePrefix="AJP_">
```

I did that but I still keep getting null in my Java application

- Shib-Identity-Provider - null
- Shib-Session-ID - null
- Shib-Application-ID - null

Could someone help me figure out what I am missing to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have this field in you attribute map file.

   1.1 And idP has to send the attribute too.
2. Since you have attribute prefix as "AJP_" your attributes will be coming as "AJP_attributeName" (This can vary too)

   2.1 You have to open up your AJP port which usually listens on 8009 and redirect the /secure path to AJP. You have to do this in apache to forward proxy as AJP.

   2.2 In your servlet/handler of /secure path try getting attribute as `request.getHeader("AJP_attrName")`.

   (Can try following too if this does not work a. `reqest.getAttribute("attr")` b. `reqest.getAttribute("AJP_attr")` c. `header.getAttribute("attr")` c. `header.getAttribute("AJP_attr")`. I am telling you to try out this because I have done this long time ago and I am not sure about exact method.)

Comment: i figured it out already. thanks though..
im not intending to use headers to pass assertion attributes.
i didnt need to prefix with AJP_ when reading.
all my other configurations were in place. i just missed that Location tagset in apache.
thanks for the response and help.

Answer (score 1):

I missed the below config

```
<Location /appname>
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
    require valid-user
</Location>
```

For Reference:
https://wiki.surfnet.nl/display/surfconextdev/My+First+SP+-+Java

Comment: It is very nice when you wrote the document in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I could get the values in Headers. For me below line worked which I added in  tag

```
<Location /login >
    AuthType Shibboleth
    ShibRequireSession On
    ShibUseHeaders On
    require valid-user
</Location>
```