# Shibboleth - passing attributes via apache proxy

Tags: apache, https, proxy, single-sign-on, shibboleth

i hope you can help me,

we´re using apache as https proxy to pass things to a python webapp - in the config of apache we´re using

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass /call http://localhost:5000/call
ProxyPassReverse /call http://localhost:5000/call
```

But we don´t get the Shibboleth attributes passed. 
Do i need to create a  entry in the config with all Shibboleth parameters ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974233/shibboleth-sp-reading-assertion-attributes-from-java/38990056#38990056

Comment: I think @Akshay is right on this, and you need a `<Location>` tag that  specifies `ShibUseHeaders on` in order to push the attribute info into headers that'll then be passed along.